# Apply a function from multiple objects in creating a single column

Tags: python, pandas, function

I have a list `Rule` objects which has an `evaluate` function which takes in a string and returns a boolean.

I want to do something like the following:

```
r = Rules()
df["Rules"] = df["Words"].apply(lambda x: r.name if r.evalulate(x) else None)
```

However I have a list of several hundred rules. I want to apply this sort of function to the hundreds of these rules and concatenate the results `r.name` via commas and have that be my `df["Rules"]`. I was wonder if anyone knew of a way to succinctly accomplish this?

This is all I could come up with was something along the lines of:

```
for rule in rules:
    df["Rules"] += df["Words"].apply(lambda x: rule.name if rule.evalulate(x) else "")
```

Desired output:

```
df["Rules"]

Rule 1, Rule 5, Rule 8
Rule 3, Rule 5, Rule 6
Rule 2
nan
Rule 4, Rule 7
Name: Rules, Length: 5, dtype: object
```

I am leaving my final code here because just in case in the future someone comes up with a better solution (which I guarantee there is one because this takes forever) they can see this:

```
for i, account in enumerate(accounts):
    cat_rules= CatRuleController.account_cat_rule(account).to_records
    if len(cat_rules) <= 1:
        continue
    rules = [Rule(c[1], ' '.join(list(c)[2:]).rstrip()) for c in cat_rules]
    df["Rule_{}".format(i)] = df["Words"].apply(lambda x: ','.join([cr.name if cr.evaluate(x) else ''
                                                                               for cr in rules]))
rules_cols = [col for col in df if col.startswith('Rule_')]
df["Rules"] = df[rules_cols].apply(lambda row: ",".join(row.to_list()), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's hard to provide us an example and a desired output but I hope the following will give you an idea

```
# First create a DataFrame of appropriate size and all values np.nan so that if something goes wrong we know
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=np.arange(df['Words'].size), columns=['Rule_' + str(idx) for i in np.arange(len(rules))])
# Go over rules, populate each colmn Rule_#idx, observe I used "" instead of None to be able to use str.join later
for idx, rule in enumerate(rules):
    df_2['Rule' + str(idx)] = df["Words"].apply(lambda x: rule.name if rule.evalulate(x) else "")
# Concatenate over each row with comma as delimeter
df_2.apply(lambda row: ",".join(row.to_list()), axis=1)
```

Comment: This was my original idea but I figure there is a more pythonic/pandaic way to do it

Also what more detail would you like? I can provide a desired output

Comment: You might try running the loop word by word, concatenate right away at each step and populate a single series of strings.

Comment: This is what I ended up just doing in the end. I still do not regard this as the best solution as I believe there is a significantly better solution out there but apparently the people of StackOverflow do not seem to know/care

Comment: Can you define better? More readable (fewer lines) or faster?

Comment: Faster and more "pythonic"